# How to recover git repository accidentally deleted before committing anything

Tags: git

I decided to try GitHub for the first time and already managed to delete all my files in my most important project while playing around. Here is my console history:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/...
git add .
git config --global user.email (...)
git config --global user.name (...)
git reset --hard   // amazing move by me
```

I searched for many ways to recover this. One recommended was:
`git fsck --lost-found` but it only returns:

```
missing tree 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
dangling tree 3178c349021f733a9fa7fa0fabd2ac34f8841bdd
```

and no blobs. So is there no hope to recover it?

Comment: `git reset --hard`? So you decided to pull out the big guns, huh? well.... the blobs don't show up because they are being pointed to by those trees (an educated guess).

Comment: When i type `git show 3178c` it shows me the list of deleted folders and files. What do I do next?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind, unfortunately. Maybe a file rescue program? From the tone, I assume this was your only copy of the program and you didn't make a backup before playing with Git?

Comment: If you have identified the tree that you want to keep, you might want to create a revision pointing to it? It's a little hackish but possible. `git commit-tree`. So, something like `git commit-tree 3178c -m "Recovering my tree"`. That will provide you with the ID of the revision pointing to that tree (the revision you just created) and then you can checkout providing that id. If everything looks correct, you could create a branch on that revision and you are done.

Comment: Commit early and often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's odd, because `missing tree` and `dangling tree` cannot occur unless there are or were commits made.  It's `git write-tree` that builds tree objects from the index (or git `hash-object -w -t tree` but this is hard to use).  (Well, the missing tree is the [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452)—I *thought* that hash ID sounded familiar!—so that's a bit less odd.)

Still, however you got to this point, the *dangling tree* object is probably what has your blob hash IDs.  Use `git show` or `git ls-tree -r` on it to get file names and blob hash IDs, then use `git show` or `git cat-file -p` on each blob ID to get the file's contents, and store those contents under the name you find in the tree.

Or, you can use [eftshift0's trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52460259/how-to-recover-git-repository-accidentally-deleted-before-committing-anything/52460401#comment91862782_52460259): turn the dangling tree into the tree of a commit.  That's even better / more convenient.  (eftshift0 should turn this into an answer, which you should accept :-) )

Comment: By the way... if a commit was ever made that has that tree, you might just check `git reflog` to get that commit back from history.

Comment: And that's the hero right there... `git ls-tree -r` was the key command to help me. Other didn't do anything. I'll be more careful in the future, thanks.